# Extract some data using Regex

Tags: java, android, html, json, regex

I'm struggling some time to extract JSON data from one `html` tag. To be more specific it's a `script` tag and using JSOUP library I can get data between `script` tags. But inside there is some JSON data which I can't extract. Here is the tag:

`<script type="text/javascript">jwplayer.key="WbtWzGvcRNi6Tk+gtKldIbx+nn6lXZFvKiaO2g==";jwplayer("tvplayer").setup({playlist:[{image: "http://img.canlitvlive.io/yayin/trt1_480.jpg?1509735585",title:"TRT 1 Canlı Yayın - CanliTVLive.io",file : "http://yayin.canlitvlive.io/trt1/live.m3u8?tkn=8JD95lXv9dOUXwtgOTBYfw&tms=1509749985"}],...</script>`

I need `url` from `file` tag which is inside `jwplayer`. I tried using regular expression for example I tried somethig like this:
`"playlist[\":\\s\\{]+file[\":\\s\\{]+\"([^\"]+)\""`

But I don't have much experience with regex and can't figure out right pattern. Can someone help with this? Thanks

Comment: I would suggest using an HTML parser, and then using a JSON parser.

Comment: Tried `file:"(.*?)"` ?

Comment: Thanks for your comments. @CAustin if you be more specific with some code example?

Comment: @sln Thank you so much. I tried to create pattern using that webiste but after some inputs I didn't know how to proceed. I should learn some regex syntax. Thank you again. If you want you can post it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing you just need some whitespace

`file\s*:\s*"(.*?)"`

https://regex101.com/r/4HldaP/3